# Set Wordpress page title a typing effect

Tags: php, wordpress, page-title

I have a Wordpress website with Virtue theme. And I want the page titles on every page (except the homepage) give a typing effect. I installed [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/animated-typing-effect/) and it wrotes I just need to insert this code:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[typed string0="Projects" typeSpeed="40" startDelay="0" backSpeed="40" backDelay="500"]' ) ?>
```

into the .php file in the theme where I need it. I just need to change the `"Projects"` to the actual page's title. 
Where should I insert it?

Answer (score 0):

You should concatenate that string with [`get_the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_title):

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[typed string0="' . get_the_title() . '" typeSpeed="40" startDelay="0" backSpeed="40" backDelay="500"]' ) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could find the solution! I had to insert it in page-header.php like:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( '[typed string0="'.  apply_filters('kadence_page_title', kadence_title() ) .'" typeSpeed="40" startDelay="0" backSpeed="40" backDelay="500"]' ); ?>
```

Comment: As `kadence_title()` isn't a core WordPress function, this answer doesn't really help the general StackOverflow community...